# Connecting to Oracle database after reboot

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, listener

I am using Oracle 10g on a Windows machine, everything works fine and all, but after rebooting the machine, I started having a problem where I couldn't connect to the instance (ORA-12514), knowing that the listener service in On. When i disconnect from the internet, oddly enough, the issue corrects itself.

Does anybody have a clue on the roots of this problem?

Here is the content of my listener.ora file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

EDIT:
When i try to connect to the host using `telnet localhost 1521` it stays this way:

[image: telnet localhost]

and when i try `telnet` and then `o localhost 1521`, it connects successfully.

When i change localhost to 127.0.0.1, the problem remains the same.

`lsnrctl status` gives me this result:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you `telnet localhost 1521`. What's the error that you get?

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in your listener config.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid please check the edited version of my question

Comment: @JeandeLavarene please check the edited version of my question.

Comment: turn windows firewall off completely and see if the behaviour changes

Comment: @CaiusJard nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change entry to 0.0.0.0 instead of Localhost as following:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
```

It's the simplest way to have listener linstening all interfaces.

EDIT: Also, you can use static listener registration such way:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = YOURSID)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = YOURSID)
    )
  )
```

Comment: It only works if i disconnect from the internet and connect again.

Comment: As I can see from your output of lsnrctl status, database is not registered in listener.
It should be an entry like this one in the output:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>lsnrctl status
...
Service "YOURSERVICE" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "YOURSERVICE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
...

But you have only PLSExtProc registered.

Is your oracle instance started, mounted or open this time?

Comment: Also, you can use static listener registration such way:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = YOURSID)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = YOURSID)
    )
  )

Added to my answer formatted.

Comment: I added the SID_LIST_LISTENER and it works very well, thank you!